# iPhone Saving File

Tags: iphone

to every one, i am doing xml parsing and i am getting two text files from the server with contents
i have stored the contents of the first file document directory however when parsing function call second time the contents are overwritten by second file, i don't know how to create two txt file in document directory for two different contents

```
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
        documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Report.txt"];
        [text writeToFile:documentsDirectory atomically:NO];
        [text release];
```

I have taken the content for the first file with this method.

Comment: It's quite confusing that documents **Directory** is a path to a txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to provide a different filename each time.

i.e.: In the...

```
documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Report.txt"];
```

...line, specifying something other than "Report.txt".

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that you can use to find a unique path where to save a file in the Documents directory.

You can call this each time you want a new unique path.

```
- (NSString *)findUniqueSavePath{

    int i = 1;
    NSString *path;
    do {
        // iterate until a name does not match an existing file
        path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/txt_file_%03d.txt", NSHomeDirectory(), i++];
    } while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]);

    return path;
}
```